# Branch of medicine that falls under scar removal

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, forehead, keloids

I had chicken pox when I was ten and I have a deep scar in my forehead due to it. I am now 25 and I will like to remove this scar if possible.

I am wondering, what branch of medicine will this fall under? Will it be a dermatologist - I am not familiar with their line of work?

Answer (score 2):

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/cosmetic-procedures-scars) lists the following three types of scars:

> 1. **Keloid Scars**:
>      These scars are the result of an overly aggressive healing process. They extend beyond the original injury. Over time, a
>      keloid scar may hamper movement. **Treatments include surgery to remove
>      the scar, steroid injections, or silicone sheets to flatten the scar.
>      Smaller keloids can be treated using cryotherapy (freezing therapy
>      using liquid nitrogen). You can also prevent keloid formation by using
>      pressure treatment or gel pads with silicone when you are injured.**
>      Keloid scars are most common among people with dark skin.
> 2. **Contracture Scars**:
>      If your skin has been burned, you may have a contracture scar. These scars tighten skin, which can impair your
>      ability to move. Contracture scars may also go deeper, affecting
>      muscles and nerves.
> 3. **Hypertrophic Scars**:
>      These are raised, red scars
>      that are similar to keloids but do not go beyond the boundary of the
>      injury. **Treatments include injections of steroids to reduce
>      inflammation or silicone sheets, which flatten the scar.**
>
> (*Emphasis mine, I also omitted acne scars on purpose*.)

You seem to either have scars of type I or III. 
The first step to take would indeed be to talk to a dermatologist. They will diagnose the scar and possible removal options.

Later on, you might be lead to visit a cosmetic surgeon for the scar removal, or there will be steroid injections.